# Spring Security - Keycloak fails with Invalid credentials after login when reached from docker container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, keycloak, api-gateway

I'm building a spring app using keycloak as identity provider. I use microservices with it. What I want to do is sending the request to api gateway, api gateway communicates with keycloak and authenticate the request (show login page if not). And then reach the service with an authenticated request. Everything works when I run it on my local environment but when I dockerize all the applications (api-gateway, user-service(resource service) and keycloak), I see the login page, I put my credentials and it returns me to a page saying "Invalid credentials". I'm assuming something is wrong with my application.yml but couldnt figure out what.

[What I want to achieve is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWKNO.png) (Every app seen here runs in docker)

[This is how the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk5ZI.png)

**application.yml(api-gateway)**

```
...
  cloud:
    discovery:
      enabled: true
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lowerCaseServiceId: true
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/master
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            token-uri: http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
            authorization-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8972/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            userinfo-uri: http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
        registration:
          keycloak-kicktipp-client:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: ${AUTHENTICATOR_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${AUTHENTICATOR_CLIENT_SECRET}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
...
```

**application.yml(user-service)**

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://naming-server:8761/eureka

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/master

spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters=TokenRelay
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    networks:
      - kicktipp-docker-network
    ports:
      - '8972:8080'
      - '8443:8443'
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=${AUTHENTICATOR_USER}
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=${AUTHENTICATOR_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - keycloak:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/
    image: xxx/keycloak:14.0.0

  api-gateway:
    container_name: api-gateway
    environment:
      - AUTHENTICATOR_CLIENT_ID=${AUTHENTICATOR_CLIENT_ID}
      - AUTHENTICATOR_CLIENT_SECRET=${AUTHENTICATOR_CLIENT_SECRET}
    networks:
      - kicktipp-docker-network
    depends_on:
      - naming-server
      - keycloak
    ports:
      - '80:8765'
#      - '8765:8080'
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: xxx/api-gateway:latest

  user-service:
    container_name: user-service
    depends_on:
      - naming-server
    networks:
      - kicktipp-docker-network
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    image: xxx/user-service:latest
...
```

Comment: the error says that your clientID and ClientSecret are wrong did you try verify these values inside keycloak?

Comment: Yes, I verified client_id and client_secret on keycloak admin panel. When I looked at the logs closer, I found ```13:38:18,293 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-4) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.20.0.7, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token```. I googled this error as well and the suggested solution was adding KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL env var and give http://127.0.0.1:8972/auth as value. That didn't work either.

Comment: From the logs i see that you are sending an empty request without clientID and clientSecret, try replacing client-id with client_id and client-secret with client_secret

Comment: @roro I had the same problem while accessing keycloak within container from react UI and set KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:port as you mentioned and now it passed the authentication and stopped recycling. I wonder why did not work in your case